# How to convert textbox value to the time?

Tags: c#, datetime, textbox

I want to convert my textbox value to the time and calculate the hours spent by subtracting current time and textbox time. But after entering the time for textbox, an exception occurred.

This is my code where I'm getting an error;

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid

```
DateTime timeValue = DateTime.ParseExact(txtTime.Text, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I tried

```
DateTime timeValue = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTime.Text);
```

also but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What did you enter into the textbox?

Comment: Can you provide the value you entered in the TextBox? With ParseExact it needs to be an exact match to the format you provide. You could try to use Parse instead to loosen things up a bit.

Comment: Rather than a TextBox, consider a DateTimePicker,  set `Format` to `time` and set `ShowUpDown` to `true`. dateTimePicker1.Value.`TimeOfDay` for getting a `TimeSpan` for calculations.

Comment: @KlausGütter I just entered the time

Comment: @GuyVdN I entered the time, and I tried different ways. (1, 1.00, 1:0:0)

Comment: @KarenPayne According to the question I must use a textbox for that.

Comment: But `DateTime` is not only a time, but a date + time. And your format string "M/d/yyyy" requires it to be in that specfic format, e.g. "5/1/2022". If you want a time only, use `TimeSpan`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HH:mm` rather than `M/d/yyyy` when parsing user input to obtain time only using DateTime.TryParseExact.

```
private void GetTimeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string format = "Valid format is HH:mm";
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TimeTextBox.Text))
    {
        TimeLabel.Text = DateTime.TryParseExact(TimeTextBox.Text, "HH:mm", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var time) ?
            time.ToShortTimeString() : 
            format;
    }
    else
    {
        TimeLabel.Text = format;
    }
}
```

**Note** the above is 24 hour time e.g. enter 01:00 is 1:00 AM while entering 13:00 is 1:00 PM